# Building a Linux Debugger C

Tags: c, linux, debugging

Trying to build a debugger in C for fuzzing.

Basically in linux, I just want to start a process via fork and then execve(), then monitor this process to see if it crashes after 1 second.

On linux, is this done via creating the process then monitoring the SIGNALs it generates for anything that looks like a crash? Or is it about monitoring the application and? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ptrace(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) system call:

> While being traced, the child will stop each time a signal is
>   delivered, even if the signal is being ignored. (The exception is
>   SIGKILL, which has its usual effect.) The parent will be notified at
>   its next wait(2) and may inspect and modify the child process while it
>   is stopped. The parent then causes the child to continue, optionally
>   ignoring the delivered signal (or even delivering a different signal
>   instead).

The signals you should be interested in, regarding to the process having crashed are `SIGSEGV` (restricted memory access), `SIGBUS` (unaligned data access), `SIGILL` (illegal instruction), `SIGFPE` (illegal floating-point operation), etc.